# Sum of square roots of the difference between an arbitrary integer and a square

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I would like to know if there exists a closed form expression for the following series:
$$\sum_{b=1}^{bmax} \sqrt{N-b^2}-b+1$$ where $ N>b^2$. 
I tried looking at the solutions to [Sum of Square roots formula.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1241864/sum-of-square-roots-formula), but since in this case $N$ can be arbitrary, I am a bit stuck. Is it possible to find out and expression both the real and integer root case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Welcome** to the site ! What looks to be interesting is the case where $b_{max}=\left\lfloor \sqrt{N}\right\rfloor$. Try with Excel : it looks to be very close to a straight line. If $b_{max}$ is anything, then ... ???

Comment: Thank you for your welcome. I will try in excel. But still there remains the case to have a closed form expression.

Comment: You changed the problem which now still more difficult. Concerning a closed form, do not dream too much. Cheers :-)

Comment: Well, I am not having any high hopes. But, let us see! Yes, I changed the problem since I forgot to add that $b$ at the end.

Comment: Try the new problem using $b_{max}=\left\lfloor \sqrt{N}\right\rfloor$. Plot the function of $N$ and look at it from far away ! Cheers :-)