# Limit of a Riemann Sum as $n$ approaches to infinity of $f(t)=150t^{0.5}$

Tags: limits, riemann-integration

I got a function which is $f(t)=150t^{0.5}$. I need is to find the limit of a Riemann sum as $n$ approaches to infinity.

$\Large\int_0^9150t^{0.5}dt = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^nf\bigg(0+i\frac9n\bigg)$

Solving Further
$= \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac9n\sum_{i=1}^nf\Big(i\frac9n\Big) \\ = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac9n\sum_{i=1}^n150\Big(\frac{9i}n\Big)^{0.5} $

And I'm stuck in this step and don't know what to do next. Can someone help me?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You should type out the question instead of posting the image so that it  can be searched by search engines.

Comment: If [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1241864/sum-of-square-roots-formula/1739708) does not meet your needs, pick a nonuniform partition so you are not summing $\sqrt{i}$.  (The $150 \sqrt{\frac{9}{n}}$ are constants when appearing in a sum with index $i$, so can be (un-)distributed from the sum to a coefficient of the sum.)