# Sum of decimal values from specific range.

Tags: convergence-divergence

When I was playing maths in python, I found some specific equation. The main idea was to sum up all decimals of values from between a specific range. The range is from $a^2$ to $(a+1)^2$. It's because for this borderline values the $\sqrt{x}$ is a integer and for all other values it will be some floating point value. My question was into what value the sum will drop to?

The equation:
$$
\lim_{a \to \infty} \Bigg[ \sum_{x = a^2}^{(a+1)^2} \bigg( \sqrt(x) - a \bigg) - 1 - a \Bigg] \approx \frac{1}{6}
$$

I tried to evaluate this in wolfram, but it don't say anything about this equation.

---

Why I think that this equation is correct?
Here is the code for it, just play with $a$ value, the bigger it will be then the value comes closer to $\frac{1}{6}$:

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

prec = 25
getcontext().prec = prec + 2

a = 100

s = Decimal(0)
for x in range(a ** 2, (a + 1) ** 2 + 1):
    num = Decimal(x)
    sqr = num.sqrt() - a
    s += sqr
    print(f'>> {x} - {sqr}')

s -= Decimal(1 + a)
res = format(s, f".{prec}f")

print()
print(f'S: {res}')
```

and here's also a photo of different values of $a$:
[image]

---

Is there any way to calculate the equation and show that it is certainly $\frac{1}{6}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Euler–Maclaurin summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) can show (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1241976/16078) to another question) that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^p \sqrt n = \frac{2 p^{3/2}}{3}+\frac{\sqrt{p}}{2}+\zeta
   \biggl(-\frac{1}{2}\biggr)+O\biggl( \frac1{\sqrt p} \biggr).
$$
Setting $p=(a+1)^2$ and $p=a^2$ and subtracting yields
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=a^2+1}^{(a+1)^2} \sqrt n &= \biggl( \frac{2(a+1)^3}{3}+\frac{a+1}{2} \biggr) - \biggl( \frac{2 a^3}{3} + \frac{a}{2} \biggr)+O\biggl( \frac1a \biggr) \\
&= 2a^2+2a+\frac76+O\biggl( \frac1a \biggr).
\end{align*}
Therefore
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=a^2}^{(a+1)^2} \bigl( \sqrt n - a \bigr) - 1-a &= \sum_{n=a^2+1}^{(a+1)^2} \bigl( \sqrt n - a \bigr) - 1-a \\
&= \sum_{n=a^2+1}^{(a+1)^2} \bigl( \sqrt n \bigr) -(2a+1)a- 1-a = \frac16+O\biggl( \frac1a \biggr).
\end{align*}
(In fact using one extra term of Euler Maclaurin would show that the error is actually $O(\frac1{a^4})$.)
Therefore
$$
\lim_{a\to\infty} \sum_{n=a^2}^{(a+1)^2} \bigl( \sqrt n - a \bigr) - 1-a = \frac16
$$
as conjectured.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks—just edit it directly next time :)